# Ranking observations by field, without a jump after an equal rank (Stata)

Tags: stata, rank

I need to generate a rank-variable in Stata. For this, I found the function

```
egen A = rank(B), field by (C)
```

to be suitable. The problem is, however, that in B there are equal values. Thus, what the command does, is, to give the same rank in A for those with a same value. The next observation which is unequal in B does not get the next number, but jumps as many steps as there were equal obersations in B. In my case, this jump is what should not happen.
Small data example:

```
    |   B   C   A  D|
 1. | 6.5   1   1  1|
 2. | 5.5   1   2  2|
 3. | 5.5   1   2  2|
 4. | 5.5   1   2  2|
 5. | 2.5   1   5  3|
 6. | 2.5   1   5  3|
 7. | 1.5   1   7  4|
 8. | 4.5   2   1  1|
 9. | 3.5   2   2  2|
10. | 3.5   2   2  2|
11. | 2.5   2   4  3|
12. | 1.5   2   5  4|
13. | 1.5   2   5  4|
14. | 1.5   2   5  4|
15. | 1.5   2   5  4|
16. | 1     2   5  5|
```

The command described above gives me A, but I want to get D. Anyone has an advice how to get D?

Data:

```
input B C
1.5 1
2.5 1
2.5 1
5.5 1
5.5 1
5.5 1
6.5 1
1.5 2
1.5 2
1.5 2
1.5 2
2.5 2
3.5 2
3.5 2
4.5 2
end
```

Comment: Closing the question as a duplicate comes with a reminder that you can invert the order of ranking by negating a variable.

Comment: Otherwise, a solution is `bysort C (B) : gen D = sum(B != B[_n-1])` followed by `by C : replace D = D[_N] - D + 1`.

Comment: Thanks, the second gives me the solution. Just negating the variable would not have solved the problem. 
Sorry if the very same problem was already asked, couldn't find it.

Comment: I don't share your dogmatism on negation. `gen negB = -B` followed by `bysort C (negB) : gen D = sum(negB != negB[_n-1])` is an alternative solution.

Comment: I don't follow. There was no insult intended and I am very happy with the solution you provided me with.

Comment: I explained in my comment how negating a variable provides another solution, contrary to what you seemed to imply. No more.

Answer (score -1):

```
clear
input B C
1.5 1
2.5 1
2.5 1
5.5 1
5.5 1
5.5 1
6.5 1
1.5 2
1.5 2
1.5 2
1.5 2
2.5 2
3.5 2
3.5 2
4.5 2
end

sort C B
by C: gen D = cond(_n == 1 | (C[_n-1]== C & B[_n-1] != B), 1, 0) 
by C: replace D = D[_n-1]+D if _n > 1
```

**Explanation:**

the "cond" function assigns value 1 to variable D if it is the first record within the group (by C) or if C is equal to C of the previous record AND B is not equal to B of the previous record. Otherwise, variable D is assigned the value 0.

The "replace"-command adds the value of D of the previous record to the value of D of the actual record. "by C:" makes the counting begin anew with 1 by every new value of C

If you run the commands one after the other and watch the data change, you will understand what the commands do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Could you please edit and elaborate a little your answer to explain it and not just give the result ?